# Problems interfacing with C99 driver

Tags: c, function, pointers, struct

I am writing code to interface a peripheral device with a MCU development board.  The peripheral device came with drivers ready for use.  I have the following form:

In d_base.h:

```
struct S1 {
   void (*funcptr)(int x, int y);
};
```

In driver.c:

```
#include "d_base.h"
#include "driver.h"

static struct S1 const* ptr;
```

In driver.h there are pre-written functions as part of the driver for the peripheral device.  These functions make reference to `ptr->funcptr` whenever a particular function is required.  Eg:

```
#include "d_base.h"

ptr->funcptr(x,y);
```

The implementation of the function is left up to me given that it is related with the hardware that I am using.

Then I wrote a function in main.c as follows:

```
#include "driver.h"

void fun(int x, int y)
{
      // do nothing
}
```

My question is related to linking the function `ptr->funcptr` to `fun`.  How do you make the compiler go to the function fun whenever ptr->funcptr is called?

Thanks for your assistance.

Comment: Why add C++ tag? It is an unrelated language. Don't spam tags!

Comment: That looks like a bad inderface for an MCU driver. It raises doubts about the overal quality of the rest of the code.

Comment: I am very sorry for the unnecessary tag.

Comment: Is the line above `static struct S1 const* ptr;` the actual line from the code (i.e. copied and pasted) or did you re-type it and perhaps make a mistake in the process ? The reason I ask is that `funcptr` can not be modified via `ptr` if that is indeed the correct declaration.

Comment: It is a copy paste.  I just changed the S1 and ptr name tags.

Comment: @JayD: OK - in that case the vendor must have provided some other method to set `funcptr` - check the accompanying documentation perhaps ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might have somewhere a `struct S1` where you can assign `fun`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct S1{
 void (*funcptr)(int,int);
};

static struct S1 const* ptr;

void fun(int x, int y){
  printf("Hello");
}

int main(){
  struct S1 s;
  s.funcptr = fun;
  ptr=&s;
  ptr->funcptr(0,0);
  }
```

In case, you have no access to `struct S1`, maybe there API functions that generate it dynamically.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion.  Following this, and further analysis it is finally linking properly.  The final setup is as follows:

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct S1{
 void (*funcptr)(int,int);
};

static struct S1 const* ptr;
struct S1 const* sfun;
static struct S1 s;

void fun(int x, int y){
 printf("Hello");
}

void init(struct S1 const* sfun){
 ptr = sfun;
}

int main(){
 s.funcptr = fun;
 init(&s);
 ptr->funcptr(0,0);
}